# Error in instantiating Object which using another Object as parameters C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I have instantiated an Object and input the correct number of parameters as required. But it gives me "Error: No instance of constructor"

Is the way I pass the object wrong?

FoneModel object to be pass as a parameter in ContractOfMobile constructor.

This is the way I instantiated.

```
int main()
{
//testing with 1 vector

    vector <ContractOfMobile *> mc(1);
    FoneModel *pA =new FoneModel ("ipX","white", 1800.0);

    ContractOfMobile *mC1 = new ContractOfMobile ("planA","C1",&pA);
    //above line has an error no instance of Constructor MobileContract* matches the argument list

    mc.push_back(mC1);


    cin.ignore();
};
```

Comment: `int&` is not a pointer, you can't pass an address to it. Also, please don't use `new`, there is no need. If you must allocate on the heap, please use a smart pointer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You MobileContract constructor takes a reference to PhoneModel as it's third argument. But you are creating a pointer to PhoneModel, then passing in a pointer to this pointer, because the '&' operator gets a pointer to the variable you use it with. So where you are supposed to be passing a PhoneModel you are passing a pointer to a pointer to a PhoneModel. If you change the following line:

```
MobileContract *mC1 = new MobileContract("planA","A1",&pA);
```

So that it reads:

```
MobileContract *mC1 = new MobileContract("planA","A1",*pA);
```

Then instead of using the '&' to get a pointer to your existing pointer, you will dereference the pointer to get the actual PhoneModel, which will then be passed by reference.

As Rakete1111 mentioned you should probably also be using a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer, which will guarantee the PhoneModel gets freed eventually, which is not currently happening as you never call delete. In fact, in this case I can't really see why you are using a pointer at all. Your MobileContract constructor takes a copy of the PhoneModel it is passed, and you don't use the PhoneModel for anything after passing it, so it might as well just be stack allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, i have managed to solve it.

eg. mc[0] = new ContractOfMobile ("a","A",pA);

mc is a vector.